# Ruby - Merge two arrays and remove values that have duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have two arrays

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b = [2, 4, 6]
```

I would like to merge the two arrays, then remove the values that is the same with other array. The result should be:

```
c = [1, 3, 5, 6]
```

I've tried subtracting the two array and the result is [1, 3, 5]. I also want to get the values from second array which has not duplicate from the first array..

Comment: a + b - (a & b)

Comment: Thank you, way simpler than i thought.. Thank you so much!!

Comment: ...or `(a-b)+(b-a)`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do the following!

```
# Merging
c = a + b
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6]
# Removing the value of other array
# (a & b) is getting the common element from these two arrays
c - (a & b)
=> [1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Dmitri's comment is also same though I came up with my idea independently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with explanation!.

Comment: You should reference @Dmitry's earlier comment since it forms the basis for you answer (even if you came up with that independently).

Comment: The elegance! This is why I prefer Ruby

Answer (score 48):

Use `Array#uniq`.

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 6]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]

c = (a + b).uniq
=> [1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4]
```

Comment: `I would like to merge the two arrays, then remove the values that is the same with other array.` this is the problem statement...your solution would not work in this case.

Comment: @Abhinay this solution is correct. it is just a different approach. unless it has worse performance it is a more obvious approach than the accepted answer.

Comment: @wuliwong how is this correct if the result the are looking for is `[1, 3, 5, 6]` and that is not the result of this?

Comment: @wuliwong It's not a different approach, it solving a different problem, that is not what OP asked for. Removing duplicates, and removing values that are duplicated are different things. Turing `[1,2,2,3]` into `[1,2,3]` is NOT the same as `[1,3]`. The first removes duplicates, the second removes values that are duplicated.

Answer (score 47):

#### Use [`|`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 4, 6]
```

Merge without duplicating values

```rb
a | b 
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Get only duplicate values

```rb
a & b
# => [2, 4]
```

Merge and remove values that were duplicated.
Which means getting all unique values and subtracting all duplicate
values.

```rb
(a | b) - (a & b)
# => [1, 3, 5, 6]
```

[Ruby Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

Comment: This is the one.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter How is this the one? It's wrong. OP asked for values that are duplicated to be removed, NOT to remove duplicates. The answer should be `[1,3,5,6]` NOT `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: Right, I have edited to get both behavior.

Comment: @PeterR Ha, you're right! OP was asking to remove _all_ duplicates. I was just looking to keep only 1 of any duplicates so this worked for me. Thanks for pointing this out for others.

Answer (score 24):

How about this．

```
(a | b)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
(a & b)
=> [2, 4]

(a | b) - (a & b)
[1, 3, 5, 6]
```

[Documentation for `|` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-7C)
[Documentation for `&` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-26)

Answer (score 4):

Let's have two array

```
p = [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9]
q = [5, 6, 4, 8, 5, 3]

(p+q).uniq or (p.concat(q)).uniq

=> [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 6, 3]
```

Also `p|q` can do the job! Decide which one suits for you.

As per above requirement

`(p | q) - (p & q)` can do the job.

Comment: This is wrong. OP asked for values that are duplicated to be removed, NOT to remove duplicates. The answer should be `[1,3,5,6]` NOT `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: In that case `(p | q) - (p & q)` or `(p+q) - (p & q)` will work!

Answer (score 0):

Probably kind of obvious, but if you have a bunch of arrays within an array that you want to combine you can do this:

[[1, 2], [2], [3]].sum.uniq
=> [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score -1):

How about `Set.new([1,2,3]+[1,4,5])`?
Which returns `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5]` is not the correct result, `[2,3,4,5]` is.